# Uploading a file using post() method of QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: windows, http, qt, post, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm having some trouble with a Qt application; specifically with the QNetworkAccessManager class.  I'm attempting to perform a simple HTTP upload of a binary file using the post() method of the QNetworkAccessManager.  The documentation states that I can give a pointer to a QIODevice to post(), and that the class will transmit the data found in the QIODevice.  This suggests to me that I ought to be able to give post() a pointer to a QFile.  For example:

```
QFile compressedFile("temp");  
compressedFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);  
netManager.post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://mywebsite.com/upload") ), &compressedFile);
```

What seems to happen on the Windows system where I'm developing this is that my Qt application pushes the data from the QFile, but then doesn't complete the request; it seems to be sitting there waiting for more data to show up from the file.  The post request isn't "closed" until I manually kill the application, at which point the whole file shows up at my server end.

From some debugging and research, I think this is happening because the read() operation of QFile doesn't return -1 when you reach the end of the file.  I think that QNetworkAccessManager is trying to read from the QIODevice until it gets a -1 from read(), at which point it assumes there is no more data and closes the request.  If it keeps getting a return code of zero from read(), QNetworkAccessManager assumes that there might be more data coming, and so it keeps waiting for that hypothetical data.

I've confirmed with some test code that the read() operation of QFile just returns zero after you've read to the end of the file.  This seems to be incompatible with the way that the post() method of QNetworkAccessManager expects a QIODevice to behave.  My questions are:

1. Is this some sort of limitation with the way that QFile works under Windows?
2. Is there some other way I should be using either QFile or QNetworkAccessManager to push a file via post()?
3. Is this not going to work at all, and will I have to find some other way to upload my file?

Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

**Update:** It turns out that I had two different problems: one on the client side and one on the server side.  On the client side, I had to ensure that my QFile object stayed around for the duration of the network transaction.  The post() method of QNetworkAccessManager returns immediately but isn't actually finished immediately.  You need to attach a slot to the finished() signal of QNetworkAccessManager to determine when the POST is actually finished.  In my case it was easy enough to keep the QFile around more or less permanently, but I also attached a slot to the finished() signal in order to check for error responses from the server.

I attached the signal to the slot like this:

```
connect(&netManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*) ), this, SLOT(postFinished(QNetworkReply*) ) );
```

When it was time to send my file, I wrote the post code like this (note that compressedFile is a member of my class and so does not go out of scope after this code):

```
compressedFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);  
netManager.post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(httpDestination.getCString() ) ), &compressedFile);
```

The finished(QNetworkReply*) signal from QNetworkAccessManager triggers my postFinished(QNetworkReply*) method.  When this happens, it's safe for me to close compressedFile and to delete the data file represented by compressedFile.  For debugging purposes I also added a few printf() statements to confirm that the transaction is complete:

```
void CL_QtLogCompressor::postFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)  
{  
    QByteArray response = reply->readAll();  
    printf("response: %s\n", response.data() );  
    printf("reply error %d\n", reply->error() );  
    reply->deleteLater();  
    compressedFile.close();  
    compressedFile.remove();  
}
```

Since compressedFile isn't closed immediately and doesn't go out of scope, the QNetworkAccessManager is able to take as much time as it likes to transmit my file.  Eventually the transaction is complete and my postFinished() method gets called.

My other problem (which also contributed to the behavior I was seeing where the transaction never completed) was that the Python code for my web server wasn't fielding the POST correctly, but that's outside the scope of my original Qt question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating `compressedFile` on the stack, and passing a pointer to it to your QNetworkRequest (and ultimately your QNetworkAccessManager). As soon as you leave the method you're in, `compressedFile` is going out of scope. I'm surprised it's not crashing on you, though the behavior is undefined.

You need to create the `QFile` on the heap:

```
QFile *compressedFile = new QFile("temp");
```

You will of course need to keep track of it and then `delete` it once the post has completed, or set it as the child of the `QNetworkReply` so that it it gets destroyed when the reply gets destroyed later:

```
QFile *compressedFile = new QFile("temp"); 
compressedFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QNetworkReply *reply = netManager.post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://mywebsite.com/upload") ), compressedFile); 
compressedFile->setParent(reply);
```

Comment: To simplify memory management overhead you can make QFile instance to be a child of QNetworkRequest object and it will be automatically deleted when request object deleted.

Comment: Except... close, QNetworkRequest isn't a QObject. The reply, however, is.

Comment: This was, indeed, one of my problems.  I solved it by making compressedFile a member variable of my class and just keeping it around until the class itself expires.

I found several other problems with my approach as well, which I'll add to my original post in case anyone else falls in the same pit that I did.

Answer (score 3):

You can also schedule automatic deletion of a heap-allocated file using signals/slots

```
QFile* compressedFile = new QFile(...);
QNetworkReply* reply = Manager.post(...);
// This is where the tricks is
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), reply, SLOT(deleteLater());
connect(reply, SIGNAL(destroyed()), compressedFile, SLOT(deleteLater());
```

IMHO, it is much more localized and encapsulated than having to keep around your file in the outer class.

Note that you must remove the first `connect()` if you have your `postFinished(QNetworkReply*)` slot, in which you must then not forget to  call `reply->deleteLater()` inside it for the above to work.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good alternate suggestion.  In my case I found out later that I don't always want to delete compressedFile after I'm done sending it; depending on the content of the reply, I might need to keep it around.  So I've kept the logic to delete the file in my postFinished() slot, where I can check the reply to determine whether it's safe to delete the file.